# MVC5 moved Controller, MVC still searches old path

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5

I had a HomeController in `/controllers/admin` and all was working fine
I moved HomeController to `/controllers` it finds the controller but still on its old path.

I should be expecting `/home/index` but what I am (still) getting is `/home/admin/index`. How Can I stop this or fix this as I need the path to be correct as the app uses the path to build menus and apply other logic.

I have removed the `.Admin` from the namespace declaration but where else is ths kind of information stored

Comment: have you checked your default routing in  RouteConfig.cs?

Comment: Yep, that was the first thing I checked

Comment: I suppose you wanted to write `/admin/home/index` instead of `/home/admin/index` and if this is the case you should not able to access `/admin/home/index` unless you have set default routing as `admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}` change it to `{controller}/{action}/{id}`.

Answer (score 0):

Hi all really weird this one. In desperation I deleted the HomeController (copied the actions to notepad). Stop and restart VS2013. Open and rebuilt the project. Create a new HomeController and pasted the actions back in. Ran it and now working as expected.

I have no clue what broke it and no clue what fixed it. All I know is its working.